# linq for records not having a value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have table with values

```
  Table Event

     Id     UserId      EventId
   ===========================
     1        1           1
     2        1           2
     3        1           3
     4        2           2


   Table Users

     Id     FirstName    LastName
   ===========================
     1        xx          xx-last
     2        ww          ww-last
     3        dd          dd-last
     4        qq          qq-last
```

I want to have the list of users which forexample don't have EventId=1. in this case it would be
User 2,3,4

how can i make it with linq

Comment: Show us your entity classes for `User` and `Event` please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `User` entity has an `Events` navigation property:

```cs
var usersWithoutEvent1 = dbContext.Users
    .Where(u => u.Events.All(e => e.Id != 1))
    .ToArrayAsync();
```